# COM ports not refreshed after editing registry

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, serial-port, com

I have a couple of FTDI devices that I need to change the COM port names of; following:

https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_132_Re-Assigning_COM_Port_Numbers_Using_Registry.pdf

On page 8:

```
3.2 Re-assign the COM Name Arbiter in ComDB
If COM3 to COM14 are re-assigned to COM13 to COM24, then it is necessary to free up the unused com
ports (COM3~COM12) and allocate the new additional ports COM15~COM24. To do this it is necessary to
modify the ComDB database by using the following procedure.
Open the registry and navigate to the following area of the registry
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\COM Name Arbiter
Open the “ComDB” as shown in the figure below . The example shows that the original value of “ComDB”
is as follows:
ComDB original value = FF 3F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00
The ComDB value is a bit mask of COM ports already allocated. This value is equivalent to COM3~COM14.
The first byte “FF” equates to the com ports COM8~COM1 and indicates that these COM ports are
occupied. The second byte “3F” equates to the com ports COM14~COM9 and this indicates that these
COM ports are occupied. (Note that COM1 and COM2 are the COM port of motherboard).
```

My registry looks like:

[image]

There are already multiple entries for the devices (the only change is ID and COM port number):

[image]

When I save the registry and scan for hardware changes in the device manager, the COM ports are not allocated:

[image]

Shouldn't there be more COM ports available?

Comment: Did you reboot after editing the registry entries?

Comment: Yes. No changes. I'm not sure whether the ports are available but not listed or unavailable alltogether. The device is seen as a USB device now. Strange.